# Values missing while loading them dynamically to a drop down list from Database

Tags: java, jstl

As my title states, am loading fetching the values dynamically in a dropdown list.
when I query manually, it is displaying all the values whereas 
when I retrieve it in a java code many values are missing. It did not throw any error or exception.

Query:

```
select distinct CUSTOMERNAME from CustomerDetails 
where CUSTOMERNAME is not null order by CUSTOMERNAME
```

I'm wondering how this could happen. May be because of memory problem or some other reason?

```html
    <option value="" selected>Please select an option</option>  
    <c:forEach var="report" items="${CustomerList}" >
        <option value="<c:out value='${report.customerName}' />" >
            <c:out value="${report.customerName}" />
        </option>
    </c:forEach>
</select>
```

Comment: How are you executing the query, using plain JDBC or another mechanism that's fetching just a portion of the data? By the way, this problem **is not** from view side, so it is not related to JSTL.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza Using JDBC. am running this application using JBOSS